# Install MariaDB Server 10.3.12 onto Debian Buster

Tags: debian, mariadb

I am running Debian 10 (buster) and need to install the exact version of MariaDB Server `10.3.12`. The version that comes default with Debian Buster is `10.3.27`.

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server=10.3.12
E: Version '10.3.12' for 'mariadb-server' was not found
```

Is there a way to install MariaDB Server exactly version `10.3.12` while still using `apt`?

Answer (score 0):

By use of [snapshot.debian.org](https://snapshot.debian.org/) you can find a .deb package that is [version 10.3.12 of mariadb-server](https://snapshot.debian.org/package/mariadb-10.3/1%3A10.3.12-2/#mariadb-server_1:3a:10.3.12-2). You could download these deb files and install them with apt or dpkg, or by following the instructions on the snapshot web site you could set up your **/etc/apt/sources.list** to point to a snapshot in time of the Debian archive that corresponds to when that was the latest release.

However, these are strange things to do to a Debian system. By definition the package is old and may not contain important security fixes. You would need a very good reason for doing something like this; generally you should be running the latest supported release either by upstream or by Debian.

Rather than breaking your system in this way it would probably be better to download the source package from upstream and compile it locally, but then there is still the question of whether it contains essential security fixes.

Comment: Thanks. I suspect there is a bug that was introduced in the latest version of `mariadb-server` `10.3.27` which did not occur in `10.3.12`. I want to confirm this.

Comment: So, downgrades aren't officially supported by Debian packages so just downloading the older deb files and installing them with apt or dpkg could possibly not work correctly. It probably will work, but if it doesn't you'd have to remove the new packages first and then install the older ones. If it's just for short term testing then it doesn't seem so bad to downgrade a package a few versions.

Comment: I tried just running `dpkg -i mariadb-server-10.3_10.3.12-2_arm64.deb` but it failed with missing dependencies such as `mariadb-client-10.3` `mariadb-server-core-10.3`

Comment: Note you've posted "arm64". Did you mean "amd64"? Whatever the case, make sure to get the correct architecture! And yes there will be more than one .deb file that is required. You can download them all and include them in one apt or dpkg command line. apt can install deb files too these days, if you give it a path to a file, e.g. ```apt install ./mariadb-server-10.3_10.3.12-2_amd64.deb```.